# Json extract Array property with index using JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I got a Json which is basically a array but with a weird format that i can not change.
Is there any way that i can get with JQ the url by searching for the name, like this?

```
{
    "servers": {
        "servers[0].name": "abc",
        "servers[0].url": "www.abc.test.com",
        "servers[1].name": "xyz",
        "servers[1].url": "www.xyz.test.com"
    }
}
```

```
jq -r  '.servers | select(.name=="abc") | .url'
```

Comment: If the equal signs `=` were colons `:`, it would at least be valid JSON

Comment: You'll need to get the upstream data source to fix how that "JSON" gets generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "=" can be naively changed to ":":

```
sed 's/ = /: /' | jq '
  .servers
  | keys_unsorted[] as $k
  | select(.[$k] == "abc")
  | ($k | sub("[.]name"; ".url")) as $k
  | .[$k]
'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a general way to build a JSON array or object from such source, here's one way using `reduce` and `setpath` with regexes for splitting up the keys:

```bash
def build:
  reduce (to_entries[] | .key |= [
    splits("(?=\\[\\d+\\])|\\.")
    | capture("\\[(?<index>\\d+)\\]|(?<field>.+)")
    | (.index | tonumber)? // .field
  ]) as {$key, $value} (null; setpath($key; $value));

.servers | build.servers[] | select(.name == "abc").url
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GsZakdOyXcC)